# What is the answer for this

Tags: android, xml

I`m new at programming and  i was making my first "Hello world" project 
when i started they told me to change from constraintLayout to relativeLayout
and paste this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context="com.udacity.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Hello World!" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9NCV.png)
I found the answer for @dimen error  in similar question but the last line still has error

```
    tools:context="com.udacity.myapplication.MainActivity">
```

it tells me unresolved package and unresolved class 
the other problem is that when i create anew empty project this error shows

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.`enter code here`

Comment: Please try to make your question title descriptive and specific.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you were creating your project it required you to enter a name (company domain). Something like `example.com` you need to replace:

```
tools:context="com.udacity.myapplication.MainActivity">
```

with

```
tools:context="yourpreviouslyselectedname.MainActivity">
```

Which could be something like

```
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
```

Comment: tried to do this but it tells me that   MainActivity  is unresolved class 

sorry but i`m new

Comment: What did you enter as your `company domain` when you were creating your project on the create project screen. You enter `Application name` such as `My Application`. You enter `Company domain` such as `example.com` and you select a project location. You need `Company domain` and apply it just like I've written above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your package name as a value of `context` in your `layout` file which is `"com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity"` in your case as I can see in provided image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Hello World!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```